# IronMQ push queue subscribers as Heroku workers

Tags: heroku, ironmq, push-queue

IronMQ [supports push queues](http://blog.iron.io/2013/01/ironmq-push-queues-reliable-message.html), but the [example Heroku push queue subscriber](https://github.com/treeder/push_queue_demo_app/blob/master/Procfile) is implemented as a web dyno. This feels awkward, because I need a single Heroku project to use web dynos that serve web requests, and worker dynos that process time-consuming needs. That's how Heroku is designed.

The [IronMQ API](http://dev.iron.io/mq/reference/api/) indicates that the push queue subscriber should be [accessible via a publicly-accessible URL](http://dev.iron.io/mq/reference/api/#add_subscribers_to_a_queue); that's why web dynos are necessary.

Is there any (clean) way to get IronMQ push queues publishers and subscribers within a single Heroku project?

Is there another queue service that does support something like this (even [long-polling subscribers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Long_polling) would work)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanted to use IronMQ from a non-web-accessible server, my best advice would be to use pull queues. Start up your worker dyno, and have it pull down any messages available every X seconds. With 10 million requests free, you're only using 26% of the free quota if you check for messages every second.

If you still wanted to do push queues and had a TCP port listening on the worker dyno, you could always use the push queues and have each message start up a worker on IronWorker that translates the message into a TCP connection instead of an HTTP connection.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I guess 26% isn't much. Any plans to implement long-poll or another pseudo-push mechanism for Heroku users?

Comment: None at the moment. I'll bring it up with the team and see what we can do for the next iteration on the API. :) If you want to, you can open an issue at https://github.com/iron-io/issues/issues and we'll update it if we decide to implement this.

Comment: Ok. But how would you connect to a worker dyno through TCP? Need another addon?